# How to use $.ajax to retrieve access_token in Facebook's API (need creative solution)

Tags: jquery, ajax, facebook, api, token

I am using the JQuery function $.ajax to get an access token like so (an access token is a string containing letters, numbers, and a vertical pipe):

```
$.ajax({
url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token',
type:'GET',
dataType: 'script',
data:{
           type:'client_cred',
           client_id:'CLIENT_ID', //CLIENT_ID IS REPLACED WITH ACTUAL VALUE IN CODE
           client_secret:'CLIENT_SECRET' //CLIENT_SECRET IS REPLACED WITH ACTUAL VALUE IN CODE
     },
success: function(response){
    console.log(response);
}
```

});

I receive "400 Bad Request" errors if I use any dataType other than 'script' so I am funneled into using it (if anyone can explain this, it would be even better).  When I use the 'script' dataType, the ajax request goes through but breaks once it tries to evaluate the response because the response has a vertical pipe ('|') in it.  For instance, the response from the server would be

access_token=1045891579010403|Y1YlFJe3gRaUndfkjC6vcYE0LW8Q

but the function errors out because there is a vertical pipe in the assignment to access_token.

How would I go about overcoming this issue?  Is there a better way to get an access_token using the Facebook API?

Answer (score 2):

baby, just use "&access_token=APP_ID|APP_SECRET" instead of retrieving the access_token, the way you try is not meant for ajax.